# How to read a PDF file using Amazon Polly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf-reader, amazon-polly

In a [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/convert-your-text-into-an-mp3-file-with-amazon-polly-and-a-simple-python-script/) (second line of first paragraph), it's mentioned that we can convert the text in a pdf document to speech.
I tried to find the documentation related to pdf reading, but still not able to get any solution.

Comment: Check this? https://github.com/agentzh/amazon-polly-batch

Answer (score -1):

Might Help you:

1. After logging on to the Amazon Polly console, choose Get started, and then choose the Text-toSpeech tab.
2. Choose the Plain text tab.
3. Type or paste this text into the input box.

   Hi.
   How are you,
   I am testing this service.
4. For Choose a language and region, choose English US, then choose the voice you want to use for
   this text.
5. To listen to the speech immediately, choose Listen to speech.
6. To save the speech to a file, do one of the following:
   a. Choose Save speech to MP3.
   b. To change to a different file format, choose Change file format, choose the file format you
   want, and then choose Change

More details [click here](http://dl.icdst.org/pdfs/files2/912024e828aa746c40f20f80965361be.pdf)